# Befunge 98: eof from stdin

Tags: esoteric-languages, befunge

what is the expected behaviour for the `~` instruction in [befunge-98](http://quadium.net/funge/spec98.html), when EOF is encountered?

Intuitively, it should place -1 on the stack, but I discovered some variation in this respect:

- the "intuitive" way is followed by the [Befunge-93 JS interpreter](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html). (The below script outputs: "`-1 -1 97`")
- [Michael Riley's interpreter](http://www.rcfunge98.com/v2.html) treats EOF as LF character (ASCII 10) and keeps placing it on top when an extra (non-existent) character is read. (Outputs: "`10 10 97`")
- [Matti Niemenmaa's interpreter](http://users.tkk.fi/~mniemenm/befunge/ccbi.html) also treats EOF as LF, but keeps waiting for user input when an extra character is read. (Outputs nothing)

Here is the test:

```
echo "a" | funge test.fg
```

with test.fg as follows (reads three chars and outputs their codes):

```
~~~...@
```

Are there actually interpreters that do treat EOF correctly (i.e. differently from LF) and still support the full befunge-98 specs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CCBI is following the specification:

> In the case of an end-of-file or other file error condition, the & and
>   ~ both act like r.

As can be verified using its built-in tracer/debugger:

```
$ echo "~~~...@" > test.fg
$ echo "a" > input
$ ccbi --trace test.fg

Instruction: 126 0x7e '~'
Position: (0,0) -- Delta: (1,0) -- Offset: (0,0)
Stack: 0 cell(s): [  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -] ""
Tick: 0 -- IPs: 1 -- Index/ID: 0/0 -- Stacks: 1 -- Mode:

(Tracer) stdin < input
Successfully set stdin to file 'input'.
(Tracer) s

Instruction: 126 0x7e '~'
Position: (1,0) -- Delta: (1,0) -- Offset: (0,0)
Stack: 1 cell(s): [  -   -   -   -   -   -   -  97] "a"
Tick: 1 -- IPs: 1 -- Index/ID: 0/0 -- Stacks: 1 -- Mode:

(Tracer) s

Instruction: 126 0x7e '~'
Position: (2,0) -- Delta: (1,0) -- Offset: (0,0)
Stack: 2 cell(s): [  -   -   -   -   -   -  97  10] "a^J"
Tick: 2 -- IPs: 1 -- Index/ID: 0/0 -- Stacks: 1 -- Mode:

(Tracer) s

Instruction: 126 0x7e '~'
Position: (1,0) -- Delta: (-1,0) -- Offset: (0,0)
Stack: 2 cell(s): [  -   -   -   -   -   -  97  10] "a^J"
Tick: 3 -- IPs: 1 -- Index/ID: 0/0 -- Stacks: 1 -- Mode:

(Tracer) s

Instruction: 126 0x7e '~'
Position: (2,0) -- Delta: (1,0) -- Offset: (0,0)
Stack: 2 cell(s): [  -   -   -   -   -   -  97  10] "a^J"
Tick: 4 -- IPs: 1 -- Index/ID: 0/0 -- Stacks: 1 -- Mode:

(Tracer) s

Instruction: 126 0x7e '~'
Position: (1,0) -- Delta: (-1,0) -- Offset: (0,0)
Stack: 2 cell(s): [  -   -   -   -   -   -  97  10] "a^J"
Tick: 5 -- IPs: 1 -- Index/ID: 0/0 -- Stacks: 1 -- Mode:

(Tracer) s

Instruction: 126 0x7e '~'
Position: (2,0) -- Delta: (1,0) -- Offset: (0,0)
Stack: 2 cell(s): [  -   -   -   -   -   -  97  10] "a^J"
Tick: 6 -- IPs: 1 -- Index/ID: 0/0 -- Stacks: 1 -- Mode:
```

On tick 3, the delta has changed from `(1,0)` to `(-1,0)`, i.e. the `~` instruction on column 3 (position `(2,0)`) reflected on EOF as expected. After that, the code infloops between the two `~` instructions.

Your code could be amended to check for conformant `~`-on-EOF behaviour e.g. like so:

```
~~#v~...a"tcelfer ton did">:#,_@
   >..a"detcelfer">:#,_@
```

Comment: Great! I will pay more attention to --trace :)

Comment: Also, if you want a second opinion on these kinds of things, the [cfunge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cfunge/) interpreter's Funge-98 conformance is pretty much on par with CCBI's.